# SQL select: how to alias only 1 column and leave the rest unaliased

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 5.6. I have a table named `client_info` that has many (30~40) columns. I need to select all of those columns, and one of those columns needs to be aliased, while others don't. Here is what I tried:

`SELECT clientName as clientNames, * FROM client_info;`

This caused a syntax error. Is there a concise way to select all columns and then alias only one column? I don't want to list out all the columns names because there are so many of them.

Comment: You need to put the `*` first: `SELECT *, clientName as clientNames FROM client_info` or include the table name: `SELECT clientName as clientNames, client_info.* FROM client_info;`